# Php - получить имя каталога текущего url

Tags: php

Для дальнейшей работы скрипта, необходимо получить из url адреса, имя последнего каталога.
Пример, нахожусь на странице сайт.ру/111/222/**333**
нужно получить **333**

Главное условие последний слеш, далее это то, что нужно вытащить.

Делаю так

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

получаю /333/

Мне нужно получить просто **333** без слешей, подскажите верное решение.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
<?php
   echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```